# Consumer Product Question not closed

Tags: discussion

This [popcorn popper question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254152/how-do-i-re-wire-this-pop-corn-popper-to-isolate?answertab=oldest#tab-top) is in kind of a grey zone, it is about modifying a circuit but also about modifying a popcorn popper. What category does it fall into? Should it be closed? Left open? I would have thought a question like this would have been closed by now.

Answer (score 1):

Recalibrating your understanding of what the rules say may assist understanding. Answering and/or improving questions, where possible, rather than 'closing' them is liable to better benefit the site owners objectives*.

- Non verbatim : Create high quality long life question and answer sets that will attract humungous amounts of search engine traffic.

Answer (score -3):

Modification questions are explicitly on topic even if they are consumer items. See the help page for on-topic questions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Stop trying to get every question closed!

Comment: I wouldn't say they are *specifically* on topic.  They can be OK here.  They are at the edge of permissible, so have to be presented extra carefully to not be repair, product use, or shopping questions.

Comment: @Passerby I don't try and get every question closed, if you look at my voting record you can see that. I don't close all consumer item questions either. I close only the questions fit under the topics of the moderation system, I might set the bar a little bit higher than most. It takes 5 people to close a question, so if my question stun gun is set a little high hopefully others is set low and the question doesn't get closed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop `except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses`

Comment: Incorrect. Modification question are *only on topic* when they come with sufficient design-equivalent detail to be answerable, same as any other question including repair questions.  And that's the problem - the majority of them lack the critically necessary detail.  When someone actually provides the needed detail, their question is warmly received.